# Printing a Report that contains sub forms i print preview

Tags: report, ms-access-2007

I have a report that is made up off 3 subforms (cover form, details form, images form)
The cover form is just used as a cover page for my report. The details form is a continuous form that displays a paragraph of detail about 10 lines for each record added . The images form is also a continuous form that displays any images uploaded by the user. A report can be any size for example the user could add anything between 1 - 40 records to the details form and the same goes for the images form. 
At the moment my report does not layout properly in print preview. what i mean by this is that for example if 4 records are in the details form in the print preview of the report 4 records are displayed on 1 page but some of the 4th records details goes onto the next page. Is there a way i can set up my report so it limits 3 records per print page, so for example if the user adds 4 records in the print preview 3 records are on one page and 1 record starts on a new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have got it , if you use sub reports in your report instead of sub forms it works perfectly